# How to intercept and validate HTTP requests in a Java EE environment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I'm doing a project and the main concept is to develop an engine for Java EE that validates HTTP requests from the client.

I have looked at one engine related to this and it's the OWASP PROJECT STINGER. My own understanding of this engine is that a developer that uses the STINGER engine sets all the rules or configures everything, like setting regular expressions that are allowed and cookie rule sets by filling out an XML file (which they call an SVDL file).

Now my main question is how will I develop an engine for Java EE? Where will I start?

Comment: What's so special about J2EE? It uses standard HTTP request like any other http server, no? What do you want to validate?

Comment: You shouldn't reinvent the wheel I think. There are several libraries out there you can derive your solution from them or use them as you see fit.

Comment: If all you need to do is validate requests, you can simply use the OWASP Stinger as-is. It does just that, validates requests, using a Java EE construct called a [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). It basically intercepts http requests(and responses) and allows you do pretty much whatever you want to do with them.

Comment: thank you for all your comments, this project is for my 4th yr final project and the main purpose is really to develop an API or a Tool that will implement the concept of a web application firewall, I want to show to my supervisor that I fully understand the underlying concept of security for web applications and hopefully discover new ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is not called J2EE anymore. There has been several years since it was changed to Java EE. Now, Java EE is a [compendium of technologies (i.e. JAXB, RPC, EJBs, JSP, JTA, etc., etc., etc.)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html). Implementing a full container is a major task and I doubt this is what you intend. You appear to be talking about implementing an HTTP server, which is probably a small part of what Java EE does.

Now, if you insist in implementing them, the starting point is always reading the Java Specifications for the particular technology you intend to implement. Download the JSRs from the [Java Community Process](http://jcp.org/en/home/index) and desing your implementation according to its requirements.

For instance this is the [Specification for Servlets](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315)

Comment: +1 - BTW, the proper name is **Java EE** and not **JEE**: http://www.java.com/en/about/javanaming.jsp

Comment: thank you for all your comments, this project is for my 4th yr final project and the main purpose is really to develop an API or a Tool that will implement the concept of a web application firewall, I want to show to my supervisor that I fully understand the underlying concept of security for web applications and hopefully discover new ideas.

Comment: @Isavel In the case you don't need to implement the Java EE specifications. What you need is a thorough understanding of the HTTP protocol and of HTTP servers and proxies. You should read the book [HTTP The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925090.do) and the [HTTP RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo thanks man, is it possible though to develop a simple tool in java to analyse http request coming from the client. I found this API jnetpcap which enable you to capture network packets its good for monitoring packets but it doesn't have the capability to filter out packets which involves blocking out or dropping unwanted packets.